# How to make power sequence using diodes, resistors and capacitors?

Tags: power, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter

I'm looking at a reference design of a chip that needs VDD3P3, VDD1P8, VDD1P0 (as shown in left rectangle at the bottom), and we have the following delays between them:

VDD3P3 ON --> 0.1 ms delay --> VDD1P8 ON --> 0.1 ms delay --> VDD1P0 ON --> 1 ms delay --> RESET asserted.

My question is, how is the delay of 0.1 ms achieved if there was no concatenating of power good signals?

Also, why do we need parallel diode to resistor (D25) and (D26), for switch (IC2) input, and for the DC/DC (IC7) input, with different polarity in each case?

**Update**: After I understood the purpose of the diode, I'm confused between choosing [RB510SM-30](https://fscdn.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/discrete/diode/schottky_barrier/rb510sm-30t2r-e.pdf) and [BAT54WS](https://www.mouser.co.il/datasheet/2/115/DIOD_S_A0004140728_1-2542383.pdf) since we already have BAT54WS in our stock.

To me doesn't look like there is a difference that will affect the time required for charging or discharging, am I right?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sequence of Power Rails 3V3, 1V8 and 1V0 is controlled by the RC networks at the inputs of each of the regulators' CE/MODE inputs (and the ON/OFF). They have a particular RC time constant to ensure a particular minimum-timing sequence as the one you mentioned. Work out the RC time constant of each of the networks to get a good idea of the timing involved.

For the diodes you question, they are there for a very good reason. It turns out that on power down, the inverse sequence is probably desirable by the designer, and so the 1V0, then 1V8 and last the 3V3 is prefered for the power-down sequence. So you can see D26 will be the first to discharge C43 by by-passing the R84 resistor, then it's the R83/C40 that discharges, and finally the R34/C47, which is forced to discharge resistively (as opposed to the charging where the diode acts as a s/c to charge C37. hope this helps to clarify...

Comment: Thanks. this is an interesting design consideration that can be used very frequently. 
what does s/s mean for diode?

Comment: Yes it is very common. Everybody uses it if required, even though many modern processors these days no longer require such a power-up sequence, bar a few ... I ment to say s/c (for short/circuit = low-impedence path).

Comment: I added a new update to my question, hope you can check it.

Comment: The diodes are really there for the "instantaneous" discharge, and any suitable small signal diode would do just fine. In your case if you have the BAT54s then use them if they suit the footprint on the PCB. Otherwise keept the original diodes used. Don't forget to test and adjust the final values for the R/C networks using a CRO, to ensure the correct timining you require in the final working circuit.